# Preloader until all Files/Audio is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image-preloader

I have some JS that displays and plays audio.

However the load time is very long, I following this tutorial (http://www.dzyngiri.com/show-loading-image-while-the-website-loads/) to install a preloader.

I'm seeing the preloaded image appearing, however it goes away well before the entire page is loaded.
I've tried variation between $(window).load & $(document).ready neither shows the image until the JS and audio plays.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>cal christmas tree canvas 005</title>

<style type="text/css">
#spinner {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background: url(images/Bitmap12.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat #ede9df;
}


</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="cal christmas tree canvas 005.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(window).load(function() { $("#spinner").fadeOut("slow"); })
// ]]></script>

<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    images = images||{};

    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}

function handleFileLoad(evt) {
    if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}

function handleComplete() {
    exportRoot = new lib.calchristmastreecanvas005();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();
    stage.enableMouseOver();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}

function playSound(id, loop) {
    createjs.Sound.play(id, createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_EARLY, 0, 0, loop);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">
    <div id="spinner"></div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="960" height="640" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You call your init() function at the exact same time as you call your loader disappering function

```
<body onload="init();"
```

and

```
$(window).load(function() {} / or window.onload = function() {}
```

are the same thing with a different name.

You should take init() out of the onload tag and place it anywhere in your script, out of any `onload` events.